# jQuery collections, function and organisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have the following code which takes a single image and applies a specific width to it:

```
function Foo ( img ) {
    this.image = img;
}
Foo.prototype._getWidth = function( ) {
    return this.image.data('largest') + 'px';
};
Foo.prototype.applyWidth = function(  ) {
    this.image.css( 'width', this._getWidth() );
};

var img = Foo( $('img') );

img.applyWidth();
```

However I am struggling to get my head around handling a jQuery collection of images, such as `$('img')` without a for loop or `$.each()`inside each of the functions (I have more than these two functions shown above).

So far the best I have come up with is:

```
var temp = [];

function Create ( imgs ) {
    $.each( imgs, function( i ){
        temp[ i ] = new Foo ( $( this ) );
    });
    return temp;
}

Create( $('img') );

$.each( temp, function() {
    $(this).applyWidth();
}):
```

This works fine, but it doesn't feel organised, feels sloppy.

Finally, I would like some guidance on the following.

1. I ideally want this under the namespace `Theme`. I would like this method under `Theme.Images` using the module pattern. Is this possible?
2. If under the namespace `Theme.Images` would it be possible to make a call such as `Theme.Images.applyWidth()` that would call `applyWidth()` on all the images in `temp`, bearing in mind each `img` would have a unique value for `_getWidth()`. At the moment I believe I would need to loop `Theme.Images.temp` and call `applyWidth()` inside the loop.

I am really starting to appreciate the point of inheritance in javascript, and would like to continue with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Theme = (function(){

    function Theme(images) {
        var _this = this;
        this.images = [];
        images.each(function(){
           _this.images.push(new Image(this))
        });
    }

    var Image = (function(){

        function Image(imageDOM) {
            this.image = $(imageDOM);
        }
        Image.prototype._getWidth = function( ) {
            return this.image.data('largest') + 'px';
        };
        Image.prototype.applyWidth = function(  ) {
            this.image.css( 'width', this._getWidth() );
        };

        return Image;

    })();

    Theme.prototype.applyWidth = function(){
        this.images.forEach(function(el){
            el.applyWidth();
        });
    }


    return Theme;

})();
```

So then you can do:

```
var MyTheme = new Theme($(some_selector));
MyTheme.applyWidth();
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer, clears up my fuzzy understanding very well.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help @mikedidthis ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like to me you're looking for a "Collection" class.

```
function Images() {
    var that = this;
    that.foos = [];
    $('img').each(function() {
        that.foos.push(new Foo(this));
    });
}

Images.prototype.applyWidth = function() {
    $.each(this.foos, function() {
        this.applyWidth();
    });
};
```